# facing the error “command 'vscode-objectscript.explorer.refresh' not found” in Visual Studio Code (Version 1.49.0) with IRIS 2020.1.0.215.0

Tags: visual-studio-code, intersystems, objectscript, intersystems-iris

I'm facing the error “command 'vscode-objectscript.explorer.refresh' not found” in Visual Studio Code (Version 1.49.0) with IRIS 2020.1.0.215.0.

My settings are the following :
{
"objectscript.conn": {
"active": true,
"host": "localhost",
"port": 52773,
"https": false,
"ns":"USER",
"username": "_system",
"password": "SYS"
},
"objectscript.export.folder":  "src",
"objectscript.serverSideEditing": false
}

I've reinstalled Visual Studio Code + Objectscript extension, with no effect.
The error occurs each time I click on the InterSystems icon to connect to IRIS.

Maybe someone has already encountered this kind of error and would be able to help me to fix it.
Thanks in advance.

Best Regards

Comment: Objectscript extension is 0.9.2

Answer (score 1):

After a reinstalltion of VSCode it works perfectly.